# Kotlin call member Extension function from other class

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to use this function in multiple classes:

```
fun <T> T?.ifNull(function: (T?, s:String) -> Unit) {
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

This is how I would like to use it:

```
class A{
fun <T> T?.ifNull(function: (T?, s:String) -> Unit) {
    }
}

class B{
constructor(){
    val a = A()
    //I want to use the function here
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'use in multiple classes'? Do you want it to be globally accessible throughout the project?

Comment: if possible i would to choose the classes that are using the function. Say that im creating the function in class A. How can I use it in classB?

Comment: too vague. Clarify what you mean with "create the function in class A" as well as "use it in class B"

Comment: I added a example. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you define an extension function as a member of a class `A`, that extension function is only usable in the context of `A`. That means, you can use it inside `A` directly, of course. From another class `B` though, it's not directly visible. Kotlin has so called scope functions like `with`, which may be used for bringing your class into the scope of `A`. The following demonstrates how the extension function is called inside `B`:

```
class B {
    init {
        with(A()) {
            "anything".ifNull { it, s -> }
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative, and this is mostly the recommended approach, you would define extension functions top-level, i.e. in a file directly:

```
fun <T> T?.ifNull(function: (T?, s: String) -> Unit) {
}

class A {
    init {
        "anythingA".ifNull { it, s -> }
    }
}

class B {
    init {
        "anythingB".ifNull { it, s -> }
    }
}
```